# Looking for plugins that notify users of comment replies

Tags: notifications

Is there a plugin that will notify users of comment replies? I don't want a email notification but something on the sidebar where a user can click and see what posts have been replied to. Kind of like a subscription thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent Comments Widget shows recent comments(including author name and link to the blogpost). You can add it to the sidebar as well.

Comment: I already have that but sometimes there are replies to users comments so I was wondering if there was anything like that.

Comment: like a threaded display of comments on the sidebar? Not sure. I use  wp comments reloaded which sends emails, but that's all it does. Sorry!